# Offloading to HLSL/GPU without displaying?

Tags: c#, silverlight, gpu, hlsl, perlin-noise

As far as I know, certain mathematical functions like FFTs and perlin noise, etc. can be much faster when done on the GPU as a pixel shader. My question is, if I wanted to exploit this to calculate results and stream to bitmaps, could I do it without needing to actually display it in Silverlight or something?

More specifically, I was thinking of using this for large terrain generation involving lots of perlin and other noises, and post-processing like high passes and deriving normals from heightmaps, etc, etc.

Comment: As a follow-up, i'm looking into OpenGL Framebuffer objects, which are rendered offscreen. I'll approach it with OpenTK (.NET <-> OpenGL).

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483903/fragment-shader-rendering-to-off-screen-frame-buffer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes. The longer answer is that you can set (for example) a texture as the render target, which deposits your results there.

Unless you're really set on using a shader to do the calculation, you might want to consider using something that's actually designed for this kind of job such as Cuda or OpenCL.

Comment: Is Cuda or OpenCL available from within Silverlight?

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: I'm really not sure.

Comment: If silverlight supports DX11, then you could use compute shaders, though this will limit you to running on DX10 hardware (I believe there's a cut down version of compute shaders for DX10 level hardware, still need DX11 though). Otherwise, I'd say Cuda/OpenCL isn't supported (would need a 3rd party DLL and then that probably won't be viable if you are doing a web app or something similar).

Answer (score 0):

Hmm its a good question.

Anything that can be displayed can be rendered using an instance of `WriteableBitmap` and its `Render` method.  You can access the output using the `Pixels` byte array property.

However (assuming GPU acceleration is turned on and the content is appropriately marked to make use of the GPU) whether such a render will actually make use of the GPU when going to a `WriteableBitmap` instead of the display I don't know.